# MAVEN как исключить 1 java file из компиляции проекта

Tags: java, maven

структура проекта:

- src/ru/mypackage/first/1.java
- src/ru/mypackage/first/2.java
- src/ru/mypackage/second/3.java

Нужно исключить `2.java` из сборки `jar`-файла.
Пользуюсь:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>

        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

согласно [документации](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>first/2.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>

                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/2*</exclude>

                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```